# HTML jquery Buttons sometimes not reacting

Tags: jquery, html, button, click

Hi I have a few simple buttons which sometimes don't react. It happens rarely but I still don't like it. It happens more if you click very fast or change the navigation very very fast.
This is the code I have for them :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('[id*=txt]').hide();
    $('[id*=hd]').hide();                   
    $('[id*=home]').show();
    $('#btnhome').css('background-color',"#555");
    $('#btnhome').css('opacity',"0.4");

    $('.button').click(function (){
        $('[id*=txt]').hide();
        $('[id*=hd]').hide();
        $('.button').css('background',"transparent");
        $('.button').css('opacity',"1");
        $(this).css('background-color',"#555");
        $(this).css('opacity',"0.4");
   });          

    $('#btnhome').click(function () {   
        $('[id*=home]').show();             
    });     

    $('#btnabout').click(function () {              
        $('[id*=about]').show();        
    });    

    $('#btncontact').click(function () {        
        $('[id*=contact]').show();  
    });
});
```

These are the buttons :

```
<button class="button" id="btnhome">Home</button>          
<button class="button" id="btnabout">About</button>
<button class="button" id="btncontact">Contact</button>
```

They are only used for showing and hiding the text and they also change the color opacity and so on when they are clicked. When they don't react nothing happens at all, as if I don't have any click function defined.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can simplify your some of the hide/show stuff by seperating the selectors with commas (i.e. $('[id*=txt],[id*=hd]').hide();).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.button').css({'background':'transparent', 'opacity':'1'})
    .eq(0).css({'background-color':'#555', 'opacity':"0.4"});

    $('.button').click(function (){
        $('.button').css({'background':'transparent', 'opacity':'1'});
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#555', 'opacity':'0.4'});
    });          
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzqwf/).

You can also use 
`$('#btnhome').css({'background-color':'#555', 'opacity':"0.4"});` instead of `.eq(0).css({'background-color':'#555', 'opacity':"0.4"});`.

Comment: yes this is smarter but that still doesn't solve the problem when button 20% of the doesn't react on click at all..I don't know why this happens? Could it be connected to css?

Comment: Try here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/3/) . This is what I'm basically using, try hitting them randomly and switching fastly. You'll see that sometimes they don't react. Its rarely (sometimes more often) so it wont happen at first but it sure happens. So give it a try a good few times. Tell me if you noticed it and if you know where the problem is.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem exactly as you said @user1880779.  
whenever I clicked on the buttons, it worked, but I could reproduce the problem with a specific situation.  
try to click on the buttons and while holding the mouse button down, move the mouse to lose the focus from the button and then release the button. in this case the click does not work. otherwise it works fine for me...

Comment: @EhsanT Yeah its a difficult thing to notice because it happens once in 15 times but it still bothers me. You have to do in random order. Not just button1, button2, button3 but 1,3,2,1,3,1,2,1,3,2,3,1...etc and as faster you do it the more it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mMF5r/))

CSS

```
.current {
    background-color: #555;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}​
```

HTML

```
<button class="button current" data-content="home">Home</button>          
<button class="button" data-content="about">About</button>
<button class="button" data-content="contact">Contact</button>
<hr>
<div class="content" id="home">Home text</div>
<div class="content" id="about">About text</div>
<div class="content" id="contact">Contact text</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () { 

    var setCurrent = function(el){
        var $el = $(el),
            txtId = '#' + $el.attr('data-content');
        // show current content only
        $('.content').hide();
        $(txtId).show();

        // update buttons
        $el
            .addClass('current')
            .siblings().removeClass('current');
    };

    $('.button').click(function(){
        setCurrent(this);
    });
    $('.current').trigger('click');

});​
```

​